# How can I write a loop to write multiple txt tables into their own dataframes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to essentially turn the following syntax into a loop to go through all the txt files in one folder. I need the df names to be the same as the txt files names except for the spaces need to be turned into _ and the names need to be lower cased.

```
abilities_file = pd.read_table(path+'Abilities file.txt', delim_whitespace=True, error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False)
```

This is how I would do it file by file... (which is so ugly)

```
abilities_file = pd.read_table(path+'Abilities File.txt', delim_whitespace=True, error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False)
alternate_titles = pd.read_table(path+'Alternate Titles.txt', delim_whitespace=True, error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False)
career_changers_matrix = pd.read_table(path+'Career Changers Matrix.txt', delim_whitespace=True, error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are basically asking how to programatically convert the file names with spaces into a variable name with spaces replaced by underscore and put that in a loop for all the files that you are looking to get data frames for, correct ?

Comment: yes! each txt file needs to be in it's own separate df.